# difficulty using software from old os

Tags: 14.04

I recently gave up Windows 10 for Ubuntu 14.04 LTS on my Dell Inspiron 3521. I cannot get the powerdirector 9 software that came with my ion video 2 pc adapter to install. I keep getting an error message that says something about error loading the archive. Also, I can't get my canoscan lide 110 software to install, either: same issue. They both worked fine in Windows 10. What gives?

Comment: Please could you make it clearer as to what you problems are (and what you need the computer to do). With the scanner you should just need SANE installed (using [this](http://askubuntu.com/a/490632/178596) or similar)

Answer (score 0):

PowerDirector is a Windows-only program, so unless you have WINE installed, it unfortunately will not work under Ubuntu.

There are three ways we can go about this:

### First Method:

You can install WINE and then try to install PowerDirector under WINE. However, it appears that (at least with version 8) [it doesn't work well with WINE](https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=29883).

If you want to try this, I suggest [looking at this very extensive answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/316025/how-to-install-and-configure-wine/316029#316029).

### Second Method:

The second option you have is installing and using an alternative to PowerDirector such as [openshot [image: Install openshot]](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=openshot), [Cinelerra](http://cinelerra-cv.org/index.php), or [kdenlive [image: Install kdenlive]](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=kdenlive). I personally recommend Kdenlive, however, OpenShot is a bit simpler and easier to use for basic editing.

### Third Option:

The third way would be to install Windows inside of VMWare/VirtualBox. This would give you access to an actual Windows environment where PowerDirector would run natively.

However, you will get less performance out of a VM than you would previously had when you were running on Windows, as the computer is essentially running two OSes at once.

If you decide to go with this method, I suggest [reading this question for a more in depth solution for installing Windows.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/187424/install-windows-7-through-virtual-box)

Have your pick of these three. I wouldn't suggest using WINE, for the reason listed, but either of the other two are fair game.

---

As for your second issue, you should just be able to use the included scanner software, Simple Scan, after installing the proper scanner drivers via

```
sudo apt-get install sane xsane xsane-common sane-utils libsane libsane-common libsane-dbg libsane-dev libsane-extras libsane-extras-common libsane-extras-dbg libsane-extras-dev
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: virtualBox/VMWare is not an option? I'd even dare to stay that would be the closest to actually using windows on itself.

Comment: @Rinzwind Oh, well, duh. Forgot about that one. Editing my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Concerning the software for the PowerDirector, you're trying to run Windows software in a Linux environment.  You might be able to get it to run in WINE.  If you don't already have WINE installed, just open up terminal (default shortcut keys are CTRL+ALT+T), and run:

> sudo apt-get install wine

Then you can run the Windows installer by right-clicking the .EXE file, and then selecting run with WINE.

You can also try the various editors under Linux.  My favorite so far would be OpenShot, which you can install in terminal the same way as WINE:

> sudo apt-get install openshot

As far as the drivers for your Canon Lide 110, you should be able to use the included drivers in Ubuntu.  On the software side, you can use Simple Scan to scan and save documents and photos.