# how to download canon driver Lide 70 scanner for Ubuntu?

Tags: drivers, scanner

how to download canon driver Lide 70 scanner for Ubuntu?
anyone know the others website to download canon lide 70 for ubuntu. 
i have download it from these links but not full drivers?

1. https://drivers-canon.net/canon-canoscan-lide-70-driver.html
2. https://driver-canon.net/canon-canoscan-lide-70-driver.html

thank you for help.

Comment: **The links you had posted here are not the offcial driver links maintained by Canon**. I would not risk an installation from there. Who knows what is in these files? This is our Q&A on that topic https://askubuntu.com/questions/75014/how-can-i-install-a-canon-printer-or-scanner-driver - **very sadly** Linux support appears to be discontinued by Canon.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Install Canon scanner](https://askubuntu.com/questions/490601/install-canon-scanner)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I install a Canon printer or scanner driver?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/75014/how-can-i-install-a-canon-printer-or-scanner-driver)

Comment: the download link from sites above are from official website...